# Edit rejected while after an hour the owner accepted almost the same one

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

While I was searching for some Android stuff I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22855233/6392398) answer on a specific Android question, which needed some code changes. Specifically, I suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20072036).

While I was trying to figure out the reasons why my edit was rejected, I went back to see the answer where I saw [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22855233/2) (an almost same edit as mine, which was actually accepted by the author of the answer):

Could someone explain me the reasons why this has happened?
Have I done something wrong?

Comment: The rejected edit tells you exactly what happened.  The reviewer rejected your edit and applied their own adaptation of it instead.  The post author neither rejected your answer nor applied any other edits.

Comment: @Servy thank you for your quick response. Could you provide some reasons why the reviewer would reject my edit while their edit was almost the same? I recently started to be an active member and trying to help the community, sorry if I'm asking so much questions.

Comment: @JohnB Your edit resulted in invalid xml due to the missing namespace declaration and the next editor fixed it. Whether he should have accepted and improved your edit or declined it in this case could be discussed - but I think both ways are possible,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post has been reviewed and then rejected by someone who then went on to submit their own edit. The top `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` was edited in theirs, where as yours doesn't contain that.

Just to highlight on a point of yours.

> Have I done something wrong?

Don't feel disheartened by an edit rejection. You're still trying to contribute to the greater good which is important. It's just at this time someone within the review queue adapted your answer. Even people like [Mr Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) will have some rejections along the way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am not disheartened, just can't see what went wrong.